# In ggplot, why my labels are not palced in the right position?

Tags: r, ggplot2

this is my dataframe:

```
    mydf <- structure(list(NOME = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PLAYER.POSITION = c("Lateral", 
"Lateral", "Lateral", "Lateral", "Lateral"), variables_bar = structure(5:1, .Label = c("ACCELERATIONS.Z6", 
"ACCELERATIONS.Z5", "ACCELERATIONS.Z4", "ACCELERATIONS.Z3", "ACCELERATIONS"
), class = "factor"), value = c(185L, 111L, 49L, 22L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is my plot:

```
mydf %>% ggplot() + geom_col(aes(x = NOME, y = value, fill = variables_bar)) + geom_label(aes(x = NOME, y = value,label = value))
```

The labels should be on the top of each bar, but its not.

Any help ?

Comment: Your `NOME` is just a single value 1.  Do you need x as `variables_bar` i.e. `mydf %>% ggplot(aes(x = variables_bar, y = value, fill = variables_bar)) + geom_col() + geom_label(aes(label = value))`

Comment: Try with `geom_label(..., position = "stack")` in case you want to add labels to a stacked bar chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way we could do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(x = NOME, y = value, fill = variables_bar)) + 
  geom_label(aes(x = NOME, y = value, label = value),size=5,
             position=position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```

[image]